# "not implemented" error while trying to deploy a simple ERC20 contract

Tags: remix

I'm getting this error not implemented, while trying to deploy a simple ERC20 token on Harmony testnet, does anyone have any idea what might be the reason for this & how to solve it. It is happening on both remix & script but specifically on this network.

Image 1 - Error

Image 2 - Contract I'm trying to deploy

[image: Error]

[image: An ERC20 Contract]

Answer (score 0):

Just send the transaction and it will confirm, I think it is the problem with harmony's side. I have tested from my side and it is giving error but when I send the transaction, the transaction gets successful.
Here is the transaction's link- https://explorer.pops.one/tx/0x4ca7d29e8dc658c051cbd85373c5ac918b8f5eb6f3b0753a1aaadc02b68ec203

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to make it work on hardhat, I guess we can't force send txn there

Comment: we can force send transaction here, just click on send transaction on the error box